# Неправильный перевод времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

У меня есть определенное количество секунд, а точнее 625690. Код

```
time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(625690)

print(time.strftime('%#d дней'))
```

Переводит это время, как 8 дней, хотя 625693 секунд - это 7 дней. Почему такая ошибка?

Comment: это 7,241782407 дней

Comment: но почему тогда выводится 8 дней?

Comment: потому что это _время_. 7 целых дней уже прошли, начался восьмой.

Comment: Нулевого дня нет, с самой первой секунды начинает идти 1-е число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%d Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].
```

То есть формат `%d` - это просто день из получившейся даты. Посмотрим что же за дата и почему:

```
import datetime

time1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
time2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(625690)

print(time1)
print(time2)
```

Вывод:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00 
1970-01-08 05:48:10 70
```

Всё просто. Моменту `0` соответствует дата `1970-01-01`, поэтому через 7 с лишним дней будет дата `1970-01-08`, поэтому `%d` и выводит эту дату `8`.

Я так понимаю, вам нужна не абсолютная дата, соответствующая вашему числу секунд, а соответствующий этому числу секунд промежуток в днях. Получить его очень легко:

```
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=625690).days)
```

Вывод:

```
7
```

Comment: можно ли тогда от %d отнять 1, чтобы был вывод 7?

Comment: @ZeN зачем вообще тогда что-то куда-то переводить? делите ваши секунды на количество секунд в сутках, и оставляйте целую часть.

Comment: @ZeN Дополнил ответ. Даже и не нужно ничего отнимать

Answer (score 2):

функция [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) - предназначена для преобразования `POSIX timestamp` (число секунд, прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UMT`) в объект типа `datetime.datetime`.

Число 625690 соответствует 7.24 дням

```
In [120]: 625690 / 24 / 60 / 60
Out[120]: 7.241782407407408
```

Таким образом при преобразовании этого числа в дни мы уже "перевалили" за 7 полных дней и поэтому этот POSIX timestamp соответствует числу:

```
In [121]: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Out[121]: '1970-01-08 06:48:10'
```

---

если вас интересует сколько полных дней содержится в данном количестве секунд - используйте целочисленное деление:

```
In [123]: 625690 // (24 * 60 * 60)
Out[123]: 7
```

Comment: а как тогда можно от этих 8 дней отнять 1?

Comment: @ZeN, я дополнил ответ - `625690 // (24 * 60 * 60)`